# Check if seekbar value is null or empty

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I am trying to check if the seekbar has value less than 0. Currently my seekbar has value between 0-9.

```
seekbar1 = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.sb);
seekbar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener( new OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        tv.setText("" + progress);

    }

String str = tv.getText().toString();
int number = Integer.parseInt(str);

if(number >= 0){
```

// do something
  }

How can I check if number is less than 0? 
I tried doing if(number < 0) but it crashes. Thanks

```
 if(number >= 0){
```

// do something
  }

```
else{
```

//do something} // but it crashes

Comment: `SeekBar` never returns negative value or `null`. May I know why you set the text to `TextView` and then parse the value from it instead of directly use `SeekBar`'s value to do something?

Comment: I want to check if the user has not selected the seekbar and it's value is not between 0 and 9,  What's the right way to check that?Thanks

Comment: What does the crash log read ?

Comment: I suggest you to use one boolean (class variable ex. isChanged) and set it to true when seekbar change. Then simply if(isChanged){ }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This :

```
seekbar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener( new OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    tv.setText("" + progress);

}
```

gets called when there is a change in the seek bar

and this:

```
String str = tv.getText().toString();
int number = Integer.parseInt(str);

if(number >= 0){
```

gets called immediately, regardless of whether there is a change in the seek bar or not,

hence, in order to ensure that the textview is not `null` then in that case, set the seekbar position to 0 in the `onCreate` right after you have initialized it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Where can I set the minimum value of seekbar to 0?Thanks

Comment: you could add `android:progress="0"` to the manifest, or in the onCreate after initialization write `seekbar.setProgress(0)`

Comment: When I set seekbar1.setprogress(0) right after initialization in the oncreate method, app. crashes. Any ideas?Thanks

Comment: Please disregard my above comment. I had not worked with seekbars before so was having difficulty with understanding them. You are right the way to get seekbar value is with getProgress().Thanks for helping me

Comment: @artist no worries. Good you found the solution and learnt :) .